# Are any major websites offering ECDSA authentication?

Tags: tls, certificates

At the time the Cloudflare blog post [“ECDSA: The digital signature algorithm of a better internet”](http://blog.cloudflare.com/ecdsa-the-digital-signature-algorithm-of-a-better-internet) was authored, Cloudflare was apparently one of "fewer than fifty" users of ECDSA certificates on the web. It seems they have since stopped (via ssllabs.com [test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html)).

I briefly surveyed several other major web properties using that tool (Google, Yahoo, Microsoft, Facebook, Amazon, Tumblr).  Only Google seems to offer an EC key and ECDSA suites.

When I test locally, though (with [cipherscan](https://github.com/jvehent/cipherscan) or `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`), I seem unable to handshake ("no peer certificate available").

Is anyone able to connect to Google (or another popular site) using an ECDSA ciphersuite?

Comment: Chrome uses ECDSA for gmail

Answer (score 3):

## Facebook

They have deployed both ECDSA and RSA certs.

See [SSL Labs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=facebook.com&s=2a03%3a2880%3a2130%3a7f07%3aface%3ab00c%3a0%3a1&hideResults=on)

## Update 2015-11-10

### About 7% ECDSA support.

Hubert Kario of Red Hat Security scans (used to scan?) the Alexa Top 1 Million sites using the [`cipherscan` tool](https://github.com/jvehent/cipherscan). This is the [relevant table from his 2015-06 scan:](https://securitypitfalls.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/july-2015-scan-results/)

```
Certificate sig alg       Count     Percent 
-------------------------+---------+--------
None                      18593     3.7038   
ecdsa-with-SHA256         33851     6.7433   
sha1WithRSAEncryption     147349    29.3529  
sha256WithRSAEncryption   320910    63.9273  
sha384WithRSAEncryption   4         0.0008   
sha512WithRSAEncryption   9         0.0018
```

### Alexa Top 10: 5/5 split

Here's a [snapshot of the Alexa Top 10](https://archive.is/kAHEZ).

1. Google.com: [Yes.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.google.com&s=2607%3af8b0%3a4005%3a803%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a200e)
2. Facebook.com: [Yes.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=facebook.com&s=2a03%3a2880%3a2040%3a7f01%3aface%3ab00c%3a0%3a1)
3. Youtube.com: [Yes.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.youtube.com&s=2607%3af8b0%3a4007%3a807%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a200e)
4. Baidu.com: [No.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=baidu.com&s=180.149.132.47)
5. Yahoo.com: [No.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.yahoo.com&s=206.190.36.105)
6. Amazon.com: [No.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.amazon.com&s=54.239.26.128)
7. Wikipedia.org: [Yes.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=wikipedia.org&s=208.80.153.224)
8. Qq.com: [No. No SSL/TLS at all](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=qq.com)
9. Twitter.com: [No.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=twitter.com&s=199.59.150.39)
10. Google.co.in: [Yes.](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google.co.in&s=74.125.239.119)

Answer (score 1):

Besides Couldflare also Wikipedia supports it since it [supports HTTPS by default](https://blog.wikimedia.org/2015/06/12/securing-wikimedia-sites-with-https/).
And do not forget https://security.stackexchange.com: They also support TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA.

BTW here are some statistic about the ciphers used by Wikipedia (and its users): https://grafana.wikimedia.org/dashboard/db/tls-ciphers